# How to generated entities having a relationship to the User entity in jhipster microservices

Tags: jhipster, microservices

I want to create a jhipster entities having a relationship to the User entity in jhipster microservices but I don't know how since the user entity doesn't exist in jhipster microservices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing User class - creating entity relationship to User entity in Microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393074/missing-user-class-creating-entity-relationship-to-user-entity-in-microservice)