# Accessing an UAA Entity from another Microservice in Jhipster

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm working on a Jhipster Microservice application using the Jhipster Registry, the Gateway, UAA-Server and a JHipster Microservice (productservice).

I already created a profile entity inside the UAA-Server to extend my user entity. I now want to create products(inside my productservice) with a many-to-one relationship to my profile entity. how can i access my profile entity inside my microservice?

Is it possible to inject my Profile class, or do i need some kind of workaround to this.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/43405851/3737815 . It's not possible to directly have relationships to entities in other services with UAA auth

Comment: @JonRuddell Then how can i link entites in my microservices to users? this seems to be a typical use case for me